# Is it possible to export a PDF/SVG as raster with vector labels?

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer, inkscape

Is it possible (or will it be possible in the future) to export a PDF/SVG as raster  with vector labels?

I'm using effects (blending, transparency etc.) which I can not export as vector. So I have to export my maps as raster. But since the map will be printed, the raster labels will never gets sharp as they get if they are printed as vectors.

My solution for now is to export once as raster and once as vector and merge them manually via Inkscape. Thats a lot of work to do with 50 different maps!

Answer (score 1):

Not currently, unfortunately. I'm working on a solution to this for 2.10 but that's some time off.

Comment: It would be nice to everyone, who build printed maps and don't want to miss blending effects or transparency. Or am I the only one...?